# Substitute Multiple Alphabets Without Using Replace function in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner of python. I need to replace  *ARED* with *TUXY* without using replace function. Example: Apple is behind a tree. After: TpplX is bXinY T tUXX.
Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the replace function?

Comment: You could use a dictionary to map from one character to another then create a new string using the mapping.  Try it and post some code if you run into troubles.

Comment: I am a beginner and I am not allowed to use any existing functions for this question. :-(

Comment: What do you think that I use for loop with if statement ?s='ABBC,BAC'
for i in s:
    if i == 'A':
        i= 'D'
    elif i == 'B':
        i = 'A'
    elif i == 'C':
        i = 'V'
    print(i,end="")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
import string
match = "ARED"
replace = "TUXY"
translator = string.maketrans(match, replace)

s = "Apple is behind a tree."
s.translate(translator) # => 'Tpple is behind a tree.'
```

However, you will notice that this is case-sensitive.

If you want a case-insensitive replacement, concatenate the lower-case characters
as well:

```
match = "AREDared"
replace = "TUXYtuxy"
translator = string.maketrans(match, replace)

s = "Apple is behind a tree."
s.translate(translator) # => 'Tpplx is bxhiny t tuxx.'
```

---

For Python 3, the `str` class has its own [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) method. So, use
`translator = str.makestrans(match, replace)` instead – the `string` module is no longer required.

Comment: Hi Rushy, thank you for your answer. Is it a way without importing string?

Comment: write your own string module, or look how its written

Comment: I tried the code you showed me, but it has an error message "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans' "

Comment: @Pydummy What Python version are you running?

Comment: @Rushy Panchal, python 3.0

Comment: @Pydummy Check out my edit – you can use `str.maketrans` instead of `string.maketrans`.